# matlab comparing arrays of type uint8

Tags: matlab, octave

I am looking to compare arrays of type uint8 in Matlab and wondering if there is a function to compare them. So, I have something like:

```
par_id = uint8([0x00 0x00 0x4d 0x4f 0x54 0x50 0x41 0x52])  
fileID = fopen(file);
# Here I read the first 8 bytes from a file
magic = uint8(fread(fileID, 8, 'uint8'));
```

I thought I could do a strcmp or something like that but that fails:

```
strcmp(uint8(magic'), par_id)  // returns 0
```

I can do a `for` loop and compare them element by element but is there a built-in function that I can use?

Comment: Compare how? One is more beaufill than the other? Equals? have the same amount of prime numbers?

Comment: Compare for equality. They are unsigned 8 bit integers, so exact equality.

Comment: Oh great! Did not know that existed. I was looking to convert it to string and compare and none of that works. This works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isequal`. It will test the size and contents of what you want to compare, and ignores the type.